# Is there any relationship between bind in JavaScript V5 and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is any relationship between Javascript bind and Jquery bind, I thought they are totally irrelevant, is this true?

Comment: The approximate equivalent of JS's `Function.prototype.bind` in jQuery is `$.proxy`.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. jQuery uses `.bind` to bind event handlers to elements, JavaScript's `.bind` is for creating a new function with specific `this` and parameter values.

- [jQuery `bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
- [MDN - `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

I think looking at the MDN documentation makes it pretty clear that it doesn't bind event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), then no. The two are not related at all.

jQuery's `bind()` is used to bind event handlers directly to an element.

`Function.prototype.bind()` is used to create a new instance of a function with the `this` keyword bound to the specified object.